# Using an ENUM type in PostgeSQL without defining it first

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.6

Usually, for adding a column of type enum to an existing table in PostgreSQL, we need to create it first using `CREATE TYPE` statement. I was wondering whether there is a way of doing the same more or less like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN new_col ENUM('foo','bar');
```

i.e., without defining the enum first.

Comment: You could add a check constraint, or even better a proper lookup table with a foreign key.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep this in mind while desiging a db in future. Unfortunately, the software I'm working on use Enum extensively. So I kinda have no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a shortcut like that.

Be careful with enum types. They are nice, but they are only good if you can be 100% certain that the labels will never change. For example, an enum for the counties of the world is a bad idea.

The main drawback with enums is that **you cannot ever remove labels**. This is because doing so would mean to update all tables that use the type.

If you are not sure, use a foreign key to a lookup table.

Comment: I think the page [Don't do this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This) should include something like that for enums

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree.